# Image hover to reveal links

Tags: css, hover, mousehover

so I have a div which will include an image http://www.reversl.net/hovers/ and I'd like for the image to reveal two links when hovered like in layout shown here http://www.reversl.net/demo/ Is it possible to achieve this using only css?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way you could do it with display:none/block

```
div.container { width: 200px; height: 200px; position: relative; }
div.container img { width: 100%; height: 100%; position: absolute; top: 0; }
div.container div { width: 100%; position: absolute; top: 0; display: none; }
div.container img:hover + div { display: block; }
div.container div:hover { display: block; }

<div class="container">
<img src="an_img.jpg">
<div> <a href="a link">A link should be here</a> </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks panda-34. Almost exactly what I'm looking for. The only thing is...the image now overflows the div. How could I fix this? http://www.reversl.net/hovers/

Comment: If you already have set your container (div.image), use it instead of my div.container, i just provided it as example. So, it overflows your div because it has different width, get rid of it.

Answer (score 4):

you can create the div with links and in css:

```
div.myimage div.links { display:none;} 
div.myimage:hover div.links { display:block;}
```

sample html:

```
 <div class="myimage">
   <div class="links"> we are the links</div>
   <img src="animage.png" />
</div>
```

obviously you have to setup yourself div positioning

Comment: Thanks. I've added your suggestion. Is it possible to have it so that the image doesn't get pushed down when the links are revealed. i.e. how would you float the links over the image?

Comment: To obtain that you have to use absolute positioning of elements inside a relative positioned container (the div). In that way position of elements inside will be relative to the container; then you have to set different z-indexes to elements, greater to links div and lower to image. Search some positioning tutorial to better learn it

Answer (score 1):

You could always use 'opacity'.

Your markup would be something like this:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <img src="example.png" alt="example" />
  <ul class="links">
     <li><a href="">Example Link</a></li>
     <li><a href="">Example Link</a></li>
   </ul>
   </div>
```

Then in CSS:

```
 .wrapper {
     position: relative; /*so the absolute positioning works */
  }

 .links {
     position: absolute;
     top: 0;
     left: 0;
     opacity: 0;  /*hidden by default */
     width: 100%;
     height: 25px; /*making this up */
  }

  .wrapper:hover .links, .wrapper:focus .links {
     opacity: 1;  /*visible on hover */
   }
```

A couple caveats to this technique:

- You will need to use an [opacity filter](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/opacity.html) for IE8 and below, as they don't understand the opacity CSS property
- I would NOT recommend this technique for navigation, as you seem to be intending. Users on touch devices (smartphones and tablets) don't really have the "hover" state to rely on.

If you want some bonus points, though, for users with modern browsers, add this:

```
 .links {
    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .3s ease;
    -o-transition: all .3s ease;
    transition: all .3s ease;
  }
```

And the links will 'fade' in - all with CSS.

Comment: This also works. The transition is a nice addition for browsers that support it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

if you want to hover over the image only:

```
div.container { width: 200px; height: 200px; position: relative; }
div.container img { width: 100%; height: 100%; position: absolute; top: 0; }
div.container img:hover { z-index: -1; }
div.container div { width: 100%; position: absolute; top: 0; }
div.container div:hover { z-index: 1; }
```

(the last one is needed to eliminate flicker when hovering over the links)

```
<div class="container">
<div> <a href="">A link should be here</a> </div>
<img src="an_img.jpg">
</div>
```