# On hover link will appear on image

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to my link will appear on center of image if the image is hover.
How to do it? I prefer to use pure css, but if need jquery is no problem.

```
<div class="container">
<img src="an_img.jpg">
<div> <a href="a link">i want this link on center</a> </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
<style>

    div.container { width: 200px; height: 200px; position: relative; }
    div.container img { width: 100%; height: 100%; position: absolute; top: 0; }
    div.container div { width: 100%; position: absolute; top: 0; display: none; }
    div.container img:hover + div { display: block; }
    div.container div:hover { display: block; }
 </style>
```

Just like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/gye6f9yh/

But I want at center vertical and horizontal of the image.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Image hover to reveal links](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9943818/image-hover-to-reveal-links)

Comment: which link should appear, "name of product" ?

Comment: @Ancient i edited, I wanted to like it but the link is at center of the image

Comment: @A'aquMuhammadDyasYaskur Can you please add your current css? Also try to refrain from asking multiple questions at once: "How to make the link appear on hover" and "How to center my link" are 2 separate questions (which can be easily solved by googling too). Always try to do some research on your own first.

Comment: @DarkAshelin  just like link at the top.i already googling for about a hour but not found, maybe i just dont know the keyword.

Comment: @A'aquMuhammadDyasYaskur Try "absolute position vertical center".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should help!
[image: result]

```css
   .container{
     position:relative;
   }
   .container div { 
    display:none;
    border:solid ;
   }
    .container img:hover + div{
     display:block;
     position:absolute;
      left:11%;
      top:45%;
    }
```

```html
<div class="container" style="width: 202px;">
<img src="an_img.jpg" style="width: 202px;background-color:green">
<div> <a href="a link" style="color:red;">i want this link on center</a> </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `:hover` property to make your link visible.

First make the link invisible in CSS:

```
.product a {
    display: none;
}
```

Then make it visible again when you hover over it:

```
.product:hover a {
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use HTML MAP TAG

```html
<img src="planets.gif" width="145" height="126" alt="Planets" usemap="#planetmap">

<map name="planetmap">
  <area shape="rect" coords="0,0,82,126" href="sun.htm" alt="Sun">
  <area shape="circle" coords="90,58,3" href="mercur.htm" alt="Mercury">
  <area shape="circle" coords="124,58,8" href="venus.htm" alt="Venus">
</map>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check once.

```css
        .container { width: 200px; height: 200px; position: relative; white-space: nowrap; text-align: center; }
        .container img { width: 100%; height: 100%; position: absolute; top: 0;left: 0; }
div.container:after{
    display: inline-block;
    content: '';
    height: 200px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-right: -0.25em;
    width:1px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.centered{
    vertical-align:middle;
    display:none;
    white-space:normal;
}
div.container:hover .centered{display: inline-block;}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <img src="an_img.jpg">
    <div class="centered"> <a href="#">A link should be center</a> </div>
</div>
```